# Nested UIScrollViews pass the pan gesture to the other when it reaches the botton

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have two nested `UIScrollView`the scroll in the same direction but alternate, the first has scroll enabled from the beginning, the second scroll view is enabled only once the first reaches its bottom.
It works, but I'm not happy about the fact the once it reaches the end the pan gesture is lost, I'd like to keep everything in a continuos flow.
Unfortunately being a delegate of the a gesture of a scroll view is not possible.

Has someone faced that issue?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //
        print("Offset \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
        if (scrollView === firstScrollView) {
            if firstScrollView.scrolledToBottom == true {
                print("Reached bottom")
                secondScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
                firstScrollView.scrollEnabled  = false
            }
        }
        if (scrollView === secondScrollView) {
            if secondScrollView.scrolledToTop == true {
                secondScrollView.scrollEnabled = false
                firstScrollView.scrollEnabled  = true
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: second scrollview fully covers parent ?

Comment: @AlokRao no there is a gap at the top. Basically the first scroll view has a main container view that contains a view at the top then the second scroll view until the end.